# curl with proxy IP:PORT not working

Tags: php, linux, shell, curl, proxy

From past 2 days, I'm struggling with a weird issue, found no answers related to my problem, earlier everything was working fine, but suddenly it stopped.

I'm trying to use a proxy say 201.17.10.12:11111 for curl request and it fails with "Connection timed out, wget also fails. ping works. 
I checked with `netstat -nputw` after curl request and it shown connection in SYN_SENT state also analyzed with tcpdump, results are

```
$ tcpdump host 201.17.10.12 -w packets &

$ curl -x http://201.17.10.12:11111 http://www.example.com
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 201.17.10.12 port 11111: Connection timed out

$ tcpdump -nn -r packets | less

22:04:00.556502 IP 10.2.2.57.62544 > 201.17.10.12.11111: Flags [S], seq 2069349153, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 2550685 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
22:04:01.556560 IP 10.2.2.57.62544 > 201.17.10.12.11111: Flags [S], seq 2069349153, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 2550936 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
22:04:03.560552 IP 10.2.2.57.62544 > 201.17.10.12.11111: Flags [S], seq 2069349153, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 2551437 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
22:04:07.572559 IP 10.2.2.57.62544 > 201.17.10.12.11111: Flags [S], seq 2069349153, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 2552440 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
22:04:15.588592 IP 10.2.2.57.62544 > 201.17.10.12.11111: Flags [S], seq 2069349153, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 2554444 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
22:04:31.604579 IP 10.2.2.57.62544 > 201.17.10.12.11111: Flags [S], seq 2069349153, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 2558448 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
22:05:03.668547 IP 10.2.2.57.62544 > 201.17.10.12.11111: Flags [S], seq 2069349153, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 2566464 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
~
```

But now if check with `nmap`, it shows a response

```
$ nmap -sS -Pn -p 11111 -T4 -vv --reason -oN nmap.results 201.17.10.12

Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2017-05-18 22:03 IST
Initiating Parallel DNS resolution of 1 host. at 22:03
Completed Parallel DNS resolution of 1 host. at 22:03, 0.41s elapsed
Initiating SYN Stealth Scan at 22:03
Scanning 201.17.10.12 (201.17.10.12) [1 port]
Discovered open port 11111/tcp on 201.17.10.12
Completed SYN Stealth Scan at 22:03, 0.21s elapsed (1 total ports)
Nmap scan report for 201.17.10.12 (201.17.10.12)
Host is up, received user-set (0.16s latency).
Scanned at 2017-05-18 22:03:23 IST for 0s
PORT      STATE SERVICE REASON
11111/tcp open  unknown syn-ack

Read data files from: /usr/bin/../share/nmap
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.68 seconds
           Raw packets sent: 1 (44B) | Rcvd: 1 (44B)
```

Firewall & apparmor is not running on both client and proxy server (Ubuntu 14.04). 
Please help since I'm unable to think now, if nmap/ping are showing that everything is fine then why it is failing to connect when using as proxy and what could i do to resolve this issue?

Comment: Are you sure the proxy is to be connected using http?

Comment: Ping works at the network layer and sees if a host is up. Nmap is checking whether the port is open or not, which it definitely is. You did not get connection refused which would mean that the connection was not established. Connection was established but the server did not send a reply. When you dont get a reply, thats when connection timed out occurs. Maybe you could check how the proxy sever handles requests?

Comment: i confirm all services on remote server are running fine and are accessbile with other system except client one. From client, ssh/wget/curl all requests to remote server are getting timed out, except nmap. i reconfirm, no firewall/iptables rules are there on both client and remote server.